# Check Convergence of the series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to check the convergence of this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Which is equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} - 1$$

What can I do here to check whether this series convergences or not? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\,\sqrt{\, n + 1\,}\, - \,\sqrt{\,n\,}\, \over \,\sqrt{\,n\,}} \sim {1 \over 2n}\ \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One has, for $n\ge1$,
$$
{\frac{ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}={\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} (\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n})}}\ge {\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} (\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n+1})}}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)} 
$$ then the initial series *diverges* as does the *[harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))*.

Comment: I can't see why this diverges, the harmonic series $$ \frac{1}{n} $$ is > than $$ \frac{1}{2(n+1)} $$

Comment: @Blnpwr Observe that $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2(n+1)}=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{N+1}\frac1{k}$ with the change of index $k=n+1$. So $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2(n+1)}$ is also a partial sum of the harmonic series, it is just written differently.

Comment: ahh, I see, thank you very much.

Comment: @Blnpwr You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ to see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}\\\\
&\ge \frac{1}{2(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Just curious ... since the posted answers are effectively the same, what was the basis for awarding the other with the best vote?

Answer (score 0):

Write the partial sum as

$$s_m = \sum_{n=1}^{m}\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$

For $n\ge 1$ we have the inequality

$$\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)-\left(-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n}+1\right)^2=\frac{8 n-1}{64 n^4}>0$$

whence by taking the square root

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}>-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n}+1\\
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}-1>-\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n}
$$
Hence

$$s_m \gt \sum_{n=1}^{m}\left( -\frac{1}{8 n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n}\right)\\
\gt \frac{1}{2}H_m-\frac{\pi^2}{48}$$

Summary: $s_m$ diverges logarithmically like the harmonic number.